# How do I loop through a list of lists in order to manipulate the contents of the inner lists?

Tags: java, arraylist

I'd like to loop through a list of lists and access the inner-list items in order to append an item to the list conditionally. I'm imagining something along the lines of

```
 for each sublist in mainlist, 
     if sublist[4] = "x" and sublist[5] = "y", 
       sublist.add("z")
```

I have no issue adding to the list or comparing the strings, I just don't know how to get from looping through the main list to checking the item's in the sublists.

Comment: [`forEach()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html#forEach-java.util.function.Consumer-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a very simple example to loop through a List of lists in Java :

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        List<ArrayList<String>> mainList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
        
        ArrayList<String> subList1 = new ArrayList<String>();
        subList1.add("A");
        subList1.add("B");
        
        mainList.add(subList1);
 
        ArrayList<String> subList2 = new ArrayList<String>();
 
        subList2.add("C");
        subList2.add("D");
        mainList.add(subList2);
        
        for (int i = 0; i < mainList.size(); i++) { 
            for (int j = 0; j < mainList.get(i).size(); j++) { 
                System.out.print(mainList.get(i).get(j) + " "); 
            } 
            System.out.println(); 
        } 
        
        // Using for each
        System.out.println("Using for-each");
        mainList.forEach((list)  -> {list.forEach((alphabet)->System.out.println(alphabet)); });
    }
}
```

Sample Output :

```
A B                                                                                                                                                        
C D   
                                                                                                                                                 
Using for-each                                                                                                                                             
A                                                                                                                                                          
B                                                                                                                                                          
C                                                                                                                                                          
D
```

Now you can place your desired conditions.

Answer (score 0):

As per the code posted in question, it is exactly doing what is required. The mainlist being a list of lists, sublist being a list of strings,  adding z to the sublist updates it in the main list since you are updating on the reference.

The java version for this could be:

```
for (List <String> subList: mainList) {
  if (null != sublist && !sublist.isEmpty() && sublist.get(4).equals("x") &&
    sublist.get(5).equals("y")) {
    sublist.add("z");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<List<String>> parentList = new ArrayList();

        List<String> listA = new ArrayList<String>();
        listA.add("listA-item1");
        listA.add("listA-item2");
        listA.add("listA-item3");

        List<String> listB = new ArrayList<String>();
        listB.add("listB-item1");
        listB.add("listB-item2");
        listB.add("listB-item3");

        parentList.add(listA);
        parentList.add(listB);

        for (List<String> list : new ArrayList<>(parentList)) {

            for (String s : new ArrayList<>(list)) {
                list.remove(s);
                s += " appended thing";
                list.add(s);
            }
        }

        listA.forEach(System.out::println);
        listB.forEach(System.out::println);

    }
```

and the output is :

```
listA-item1 appended thing
listA-item2 appended thing
listA-item3 appended thing
listB-item1 appended thing
listB-item2 appended thing
listB-item3 appended thing
```

Just take attention to the fact that I am creating new ArralyList in foreach statement :

```
for (List<String> list : new ArrayList<>(parentList)) {

            for (String s : new ArrayList<>(list)) {
```

if you do not do that you will get `java.util.ConcurrentModificationException`